# My site is not working because of this: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare be_themes_contact_authentication

Tags: fatal-error

I´m trying to update some plugins. Sudenly this message was on my site:

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare be_themes_contact_authentication() (previously declared in /home/content/24/11734224/html/wp-content/plugins/be-page-builder/functions/be-pb-ajax-handler.php:12) in /home/content/24/11734224/html/wp-content/themes/oshin/ajax-handler.php on line 41

Now i can not get in the site, admin, or nothing. How can I fixit?

Answer (score 1):

Do one thing, connect with the FTP and go to the following path,

rootfolder\wp-content\

rename the plugins folder to anything which will be there to the above path folder. Get back to the site and activate all the plugins one by one. This will tell you which plugin is the cause of the issue.